# How to create an encrypted container (dynamically expandable) on OpenBSD

Tags: files, encryption, openbsd, gpg

**On OpenBSD**, how/with what I can create an encrypted container that can later be dynamically expanded? Can I do it with GPG? (password protection is enough)

So, if I open this container and put files in it, it would dynamically expand as more files are put in it.

Please do not recommend a Linux solution (e.g. TrueCrypt) without checking that it works on OpenBSD.

Comment: Do you need to be able to take files out, or replace them without wasting space?

Comment: May I know, why you are rejecting truecrypt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official encrypted container on OpenBSD is through vnode pseudo devices, set up with [`vnconfig`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=vnconfig&sektion=8&manpath=OpenBSD+Current). As far as I know, these cannot be resized: you'd have to create another, larger container and copy the data.

[Encfs](http://www.arg0.net/encfs) is a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) flesystem that performs encryption file by file (so there is no container size issue). There is a [FreeBSD port](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/fusefs-encfs/), which I think could easily be adapted to OpenBSD.

An alternative approach is to use gpg. You can edit the file in an editor such as Emacs or Vim that automatically decrypts and encrypts the file on the fly. But if you want to use the file in some other application, you'll have to encrypt and decrypt manually.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org). See [this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562104/406281) to a similar question on StackOverflow a while ago.

---

***Edit:***

I don't think you should downvote perfectly good answers just because you weren't explicit enough in your question -- only a tag? Anyway... GnuPG / PGP can't do what you want. Check out [Comparison of disk encryption software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software) on Wikipedia. Looks like your only choice is "svnd / vnconfig".

Comment: Ecryptfs relies on Linux kernel support. It isn't available on OpenBSD.

Comment: Indeed Gilles. I didn't notice the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in this regard  [truecrypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt)  is your best friend.

Comment: nono, no truecrypt, sorry, I updated the Q

Comment: Have you tried cryptsetup and luksOpen ?

Comment: on an OpenBSD box?

Comment: If you have source code, then does it matter ?

Comment: @SHW I can't find any sign that Truecrypt is works on OpenBSD. The only mention of *BSD on the TrueCrypt site is [this page about FreeBSD](http://www.truecrypt.org/misc/freebsd) which states that while it is possible to compile the code, it is not recommended because the resulting code is likely to be buggy.

Comment: @Gilles,Please have a look at [this][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software#Operating_systems

Comment: @SHW I see a Wikipedia page of questionable up-to-dateness, with a “no” in the cell for TrueCrypt/OpenBSD. How is this relevant (besides a weak confirmation that TrueCrypt indeed does not support OpenBSD)?

Comment: @Gilles, I posted link to say that openBSD only supports "softraid / RAID C" and "svnd / vnconfig". So these are the two choices for the person-in-question.